# How to correctly time speed of writing to a disk (i.e. file) in C

Tags: c, linux, time

I have a Zynq SoC which runs a Linux system and would like to time the speed at which I can write to its SD card in C.

I have tried out `clock()` and `clock_gettime()` where for the latter, I have done the following:

```
#define BILLION 1000000000.0
#define BUFFER_SIZE 2097152
...

for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    memcpy(buf, channel->dma + offset, BUFFER_SIZE);
    
    /* Open file for output */
    FILE *f = fopen(path, "w");

    /* Start timer */
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    /* Write data from cpu ram to sd card*/
    fwrite(buf, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, f);
    fclose(f);

    /* Stop timer and report result */
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    elapsed_time = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / BILLION;
    printf("%lf seconds\n", elapsed_time);
}
```

The times that I'm getting are around 0.019 seconds for 2097152 bytes which I believe is wrong because the speed of writing to the SD card is quoted as 10 MB/s and can't possibly be the 110 MB/s that I appear to be getting. When I, instead put the timing code outside the loop and, basically, time how long it takes to write the whole 100*BUFFER_SIZE, I get a more reasonable 18 MB/s.

My question is, is it incorrect to try to time a single fwrite operation? Does `clock_gettime()` not give me the adequate accuracy/precision for that? I would like to have the most accurate value possible for how quickly I can write to the disk because it is a very important parameter in the design of the system and so this discrepancy I'm getting is rather disconcerting.

Comment: `clock()` can have quite crude granularity on some systems, making it only suitable for timing operations that take several seconds. You also have to turn off disk buffering, or write such a large quantity that most of it can't still be in a cache.

Comment: There's lots of "levels" at which buffering can occur: hardware level, device driver level, operating system level, C library level (you got this covered with `fclose()`), application level (you got this covered with `fwrite()`)...

Comment: Is it incorrect to time a single `fwrite` operation? For one byte, yes. For `SIZE_MAX` bytes, no.

Comment: Btw, keep in mind that you are writing a program to calculate latency, not throughput. It is not trivial to calculate the throughput from the latency: you seem to assume that the `latency = size_of_write / write_speed`, which is generally wrong due to page caches (Linux), `fclose` (Linux running, disk possibly idle), etc.
A better option might be to make a lot of changes to the pages in the page cache, and then time the fsync operation.

Comment: Thanks all. Thanks @TSG for the catch on naive latency formula. Would have made for an embarrassing section in my report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux Kernel often caches read write access to disk storage. That is, it returns from the write call and does the actual writing in the background. It does that transparently, so that if you would read the same file, just after writing, you would get the results you wrote, even if they are not yet transferred and written completely to disk.

To force a complete write you can call the [fsync](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) function. It blocks until all file IO for a specific file has completed. In your case a call to

```
#include <unistd.h>

...
fwrite(...);
fsync(fileno(f));
```

should suffice.

**Edit**
as @pmg mentioned in the comments, there is also be buffering at stream level. Although it probably is not that large of a buffer, you can force the stream buffer to be written with a call to `fflush()` before the `fsync`.

Comment: Thanks! ```fsync``` worked like magic. I'll ```fflush``` to the file as well and move ```fclose()``` out of the timing just to be safe.

Comment: You might also want to try `open` with `O_SYNC`, but this shouldn't deviate much from using `fsync` after a write.